# Can I iterate through Vuex state data with a for loop in a Getter?

Tags: vue.js, for-loop, chart.js, vuex, getter

I am working on a weather app in Vuex and Chart.js. I succeeded to retrieve the data from an API with an axios call and to store the data in Vuex state and to display it with Getters in a chart. The problem is that the temperature data is divided hourly a week in advance, so there are 7 times twenty-four values ​​in one array. I don't want to display the chart in hourly divisions, but in daily divisions. So I should divide the array into 24 units, calculate an average from each of them, and then create a new array from the new 7 values.

I tried to run a for loop in a getter:

```
    getters: {

    budapestTemp: state => {
      let arr = state.budapest.hourly?.temperature_2m;
      let avgArray = [];

      for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 24) { 
          total = arr[i] + (arr[i+1] || 0)+ (arr[i+2] || 0) ;
          avg = total/3;
          avgArray.push(Math.round(avg));
        };
        return avgArray;
    },
}
```

The getter is mapped with mapGetter in the chartData object of the component, so it should work, but I get the following error message in the console and the browser does not display anything:

Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: i is not defined
at budapestTemp (index.js?68eb:24:1)
at wrappedGetter (vuex.esm-bundler.js?03c9:352:1)

I have no clue how to solve this, I would really appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: you have to initiate the `i` variable used in for loop: `for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 24) {`

Comment: Yes, I know. But now it returns this error message:

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

OK, I changed everywhere 'arr' to 'state.budapest.hourly?.temperature_2m', now I don't get any error messages, but teh diagram still does not display the data.

Comment: I suppose your store is populated asynchronously, so you have to check your component and see when the chart object is created (I think it is created before fetching data completes). maybe set up a watcher to reconstruct the chart object when the getter result changes. The problem now is not in the code you provided

Comment: what does `arr` or `state.budapest` log

Comment: I solved it, I had to put the for loop in an if (arr) statement. Now it works.